# How do I peek a big endian value from bytes::BytesMut?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm converting some of my old code into futures async/await style and have hit a problem.

I'm using the tokio_util crate as I'm dealing with a framed protocol with the `Encoder` and `Decoder` traits from this crate.

For the `Decoder`, I need to peek at the first 2 bytes of the passed `bytes::BytesMut` struct as these bytes hold the length of the frame. However the `BytesMut` struct does not easily allow this. My function is:

```
impl Decoder for MyCodec {
    type Item = ServerMessage;
    type Error = io::Error;

    fn decode(&mut self, buf: &mut BytesMut) -> io::Result<Option<ServerMessage>> {
        if buf.len() <= 2 {
            return Ok(None);
        };
```

The next step will occur if at least 2 bytes are in buf and these should be read in big endian format to proceed with the decoder. Trouble is I can't see how to do that with a `BytesMut` structure.

Comment: I don't see the link with async

Comment: The link is that I'm using the tokio crate which uses async read and writes and the Decoder trait signature (which uses the bytes crate) is defined in tokio_util.

Comment: but your question is about BytesMut, tokio is off topic.

Comment: No, it's tokio that's forcing me to use BytesMut so it's involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of experimentation I think this may be the optimal way to do this. From the [standard library documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html#method.from_be_bytes) it says "When starting from a slice rather than an array, fallible conversion APIs can be used" under the "from_be_bytes" function.

```
use bytes::BytesMut;
use std::convert::TryInto;

impl Decoder for MyCodec {
    type Item = ServerMessage;
    type Error = io::Error;

    fn decode(&mut self, buf: &mut BytesMut) -> io::Result<Option<ServerMessage>> {
        if buf.len() <= 2 {
            return Ok(None);
        };

        let frame_size = u16::from_be_bytes(buf[..2].try_into().unwrap());

        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [byteorder crate](https://docs.rs/byteorder/1.3.2/byteorder/)

```
use std::io::Cursor;
use byteorder::{BigEndian, ReadBytesExt};

impl Decoder for MyCodec {
    type Item = ServerMessage;
    type Error = std::io::Error;

    fn decode(&mut self, buf: &mut BytesMut) -> std::io::Result<Option<ServerMessage>> {
        if buf.len() <= 2 {
            return Ok(None);
        };

        let mut rdr = Cursor::new(&buf[..]);
        let package_length = rdr.read_u16::<BigEndian>()?;

        return Ok(None);
    }

}
```

[rust.playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a26dade78c203515f1a2c2653c118543)

Comment: Why are you making 2 calls to `read_u16`? A single call to `read_u16` will read 2 bytes and return a `u16`...

Comment: I missed that part of question. Just showed a method how to read bytes in a correct format. Updated my answer one more time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's quite annoying because this was very ergonomic in the previous version of the bytes crate as I just did let size = buf[..2].into_buf().get_u16_be().

Answer (score 0):

The bytes crate already has what you are looking for.  You just need to bring in the `bytes::Buf` trait, which will give you `get_u16()` for both `bytes::BytesMut` and `std::io::Cursor`.

```rust
use bytes::{BytesMut, Buf};
use std::io::Cursor;
use tokio_util::codec::Decoder;

struct MyCodec;
struct ServerMessage;

impl Decoder for MyCodec {
    type Item = ServerMessage;
    type Error = std::io::Error;

    fn decode(&mut self, buf: &mut BytesMut) -> std::io::Result<Option<ServerMessage>> {
        if buf.len() <= 2 {
            return Ok(None);
        };

        let mut peeker = Cursor::new(&buf[..2]);
        let size = peeker.get_u16();

        if buf.len() >= (size + 2) as usize {
            // swallow the size header
            let _ = buf.get_u16();

            // read frame bytes
            Ok(Some(ServerMessage))
        }
        
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```